# std::vector.at(). Does it return a reference or a copy?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I've just started learning C++ and I'm trying how `std::vector` works.

I have this test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> element1 = { 1, 2,3 };
    std::vector<int> element2 = { 4, 5, 6 };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> lista = { element1, element2 };

    std::vector<int> var = lista.at(0);

    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = var.begin(); i != var.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    var[0] = 22;


    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = var.begin(); i != var.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;


    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = lista.at(0).begin(); i != lista.at(0).end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That outputs:

```
1 2 3
22 2 3
1 2 3
```

I think that at operator doesn't return a reference (but maybe I'm wrong), so I think it returns a new vector, isn't it?

But, if I want to get a reference, how can I do it?

**UPDATE:**

And... if I want to get in `lista` the references of `element1` and `element2` instead of a copy?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at

Comment: @S.Dev But, if it returns a reference, why there isn't any change on lista after changing var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think that at operator doesn't return a reference (but maybe I'm wrong)

You're wrong indeed. `vector::at` returns a reference, as shown in the declaration:

```
reference       at( size_type pos );
const_reference at( size_type pos ) const;
```

However, `std::vector<int> var` is not a reference, and you copy initialize it from the returned reference.

> But, if I want to get a reference, how can I do it?

To get a reference, you need a reference variable where you can capture the reference returned by `at`:

```
std::vector<int>& var = lista.at(0);
//              ^ a reference
```

> And also here, `std::vector<std::vector<int>> lista = { element1, element2 };`, I think there is a copy of `element1` and `element2` in `lista` vector.

That's right.

> If I don't want to create a copy of `element1` and `element2`, what do I have to do?

If you don't want to store (copies of) vectors in the outer vector, then you need to store something else. You cannot store references in containers, but you can store `std::reference_wrapper`s or pointers. For example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>*> lista = { &element1, &element2 };
```

You can then get a reference to the pointed vector using the indirection operator.

---

It's not clear from your example what you're trying to do, perhaps it might make sense to have a vector of vectors, and let `element1` and `element2` be references instead:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> lista = {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
};
std::vector<int>& element1 = lista[0];
std::vector<int>& element2 = lista[1];
```

---

If you only want to avoid copying contents of the subvectors, and if you don't intend to use `element1` and `element2` afterwards, then there is another way: You can move construct the subvectors of `lista`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> lista = {
    std::move(element1),
    std::move(element2),
};
// element1 and elemenet2 are now in an unspecified state
```

Comment: I'm trying to reuse the vectors inside the `lista` vector and don't create copies of them. I will create **N** `elementN` vectors and add them to the `lista` vector and I don't want to create copies or new vectors.

Comment: But, this example is only a test. I wanted to know how `vector` works.

Answer (score 10):

`at` returns a reference (and a `const` reference for the `const` version).

Your issue is that you are taking an explicit value copy in your code with `std::vector<int> var = lista.at(0);`. The obvious fix is `auto& var = lista.at(0);`.

Finally, if you wish to avoid a value copy of `element1` and `element2`, you can remove them and write

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> lista = { { 1, 2,3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

instead.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at

Comment: So it returns a reference but if you store that reference in a `std::vector<int>` variable instead of a `std::vector<int>&` variable it instead stores a copy of what's at the reference?

Comment: @NickA: Yup, C++ works like that in general. If you copy a reference to a value, then a value copy of that reference is taken.

Answer (score 5):

`at` returns a reference.

You store it in a copy here `std::vector<int> var = lista.at(0);`

You might do `std::vector<int>& var = lista.at(0);` to get reference.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is not a reference, its just another variable like `b` below.

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;
int &bref = a;
b=6;
cout<<a<<endl; // a is still 5
bref = 6;
cout<<a<<endl; // a is now 6
```

What you want is `bref` and not `b` ie

```
std::vector<int> &var = lista.at(0);
```